# Installing knncat

Tags: r, ubuntu, package

I am using R in Ubuntu 10.04.

I need to understand the documentation.
Installing **knncat** I get this error message:

```
gcc -I/usr/share/R/include     -I . -DUSE_R_ALLOC -DCALL_FROM_R -fpic 
-std=gnu99 -O3 -pipe  -g -c ranlib.c -o ranlib.o gcc -I/usr/share/R/include     -I . -DUSE_R_ALLOC -DCALL_FROM_R -fpic  -std=gnu99 -O3 -pipe  -g -c utilsR.c -o utilsR.o gcc -shared -o knncat.so com.o dodisc.o donn.o donnwrap.o dsort.o linpack.o matrix.o
objective.o ords.o ranlib.o utilsR.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm
-L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [knncat.so] Error 1 ERROR:
compilation failed for package ‘knncat’
```

[In the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#LAPACK) I find this recomendation:

```
Provision is made for using an external LAPACK library, principally to 
cope with BLAS libraries which contain a copy of LAPACK (such as sunperf 
on Solaris, vecLib on OS X and ACML on ‘ix86’/‘x86_64’ Linux)
```

If it is mandatory (?), I should use this code:

```
--with-lapack="-L/path/to/libs -llapack -lcblas"
```

But where? I am using the standard installation of packages in R.

```
install.packages('knncat')
```

I am not sure of:

- Is it mandatory to install lapack?  I do have BLAS + LAPACK.
- How to install a package without using install.packages()?
- which are the choices I have now?

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel  Thank you

I did this:
**sudo apt-get install r-base-dev**

And got this:
_Unmet dependencies:
  r-base-dev: Depends: libbz2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages_

Then I did this order:
**sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev**

And the answer was:

_unmet dependencies:
  libbz2-dev: Depends: libbz2-1.0 (= 1.0.5-4) but 1.0.5-4ubuntu0.1 is to be installed_

Tried this order:
**sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0**

And got this answer
**libbz2-1.0 is already the newest version.**

Then, there is a missing link somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an old version of R.  Even when I did upgrade, it does not fixed. 
I followed this orders: from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=377323

```
sudo aptitude install r-base r-recommended
```

In R

```
install.packages('knncat')
```

Now it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Please install the `r-base-dev` package, which will take care of the `-dev` packages for LAPACK and BLAS as well.

Comment: Thank you Eddelbuettel.

I did this: